# How to get the index of the field from my array properly in Laravel blade?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

**This is the "show" function in my Controller :**

```
public function show($nform)
{
    $plan = PlanFormation::findOrFail($nform);

    $plan_props = PlanFormation::select(
            'clients.raisoci',
            'clients.nrc_entrp',
            'intervenants.nom',
            'intervenants.prenom')

                ->join('clients', 'clients.nrc_entrp', '=', 'plan_formations.nrc_e')
                ->join('intervenants', 'intervenants.id_interv', '=', 'plan_formations.id_inv')
                ->where('plan_formations.n_form', '=', $nform)
                ->get();

return view('planformation.detail',  ['plan_props' => $plan_props, 'plan' => $plan]);
}
```

**Here is my Blade :**

```
<div class="card-header">
    <a class="btn btn-dark btn-sm bu-lg-ic" href="/planformation"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i></a>
    <h3 class="card-title card-h3">Plan N° {{ $plan->n_form }} > {{ $plan_props['raisoci'] }}</h3>
</div>
```

**I got "Undefined index 'raisoci' when I use `$plan_props['raisoci']` in the blade**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example `$plan_props` is not an array with element ['raisoci'] but a collection of items. So you can get the first element of this collection and call its `'raisoci'` property:

```
{{ $plan_props[0]['raisoci'] }}
```

or

```
{{ $plan_props[0]->raisoci }}
```

You may also call `first()` method instead of `get()` in your query. In this case you'll get exactly what you expected in your example:

```
$plan_props = PlanFormation::select(...)
                 ...
                 ->where('plan_formations.n_form', '=', $nform)
                 ->first();
```

Comment: It worked for me when I used `->first()` and I left `{{ $plan_props['raisoci'] }}` as it, Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

It worked when I used `->first()` and I left `{{ $plan_props['raisoci'] }}` as it's
**The third answer is the correct answer**
Thank you [Manssor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5350910/manzor) for your help